# How to use AJAX in multiple drop down in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I know this is a stupid question but i am new with AJAX and
i tried many of the code i got from internet but still not able to do this simple thing
so at last i am posting my question here
something is wrong and when i select option in first drop down list
nothing happens
database table name is sub_menu and its fields are as follows
id,sub_item_name,item_name,price

this is my script i put on additem.php file

```
    <script>
         function showSubItem(sel) {
    var item_name = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;  
    $("#subItemTr").html( "" );
    if (item_name.length > 0 ) {

 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "subitem.php",
        data: "item_name="+item_name,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {    
            $("#subItemTr").html( html );
        }
    });
}
}
</script>
```

and he is my both drop down menu both are in a table form
My master menu is still working and displaying all option from database so i am not posting that
part here

```
    <tr>
  <td width="251">Select Master Menu Name</td>
  <td width="47">:</td>
  <td width="342"><select name="iname" id="iname" class="form-control" onChange="showSubItem(this);">
  <option selected="selected">Select Main Menu</option>
  <?php
    $abc = "select * from main_menu";
    $lkg = mysql_query($abc);
    while($ukg = mysql_fetch_row($lkg))
    {
  ?>
  <option><?php echo $ukg[1]; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
  </select>      </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td width="251">Sub Item Name</td>
  <td width="47">:</td>
  <td width="342" id="subItemTr" ><select name="subname" id="subname" class="form-control">
  <option selected="selected">Select Sub Item</option>
  </select></td>
</tr>
```

And here is my subitem.php file code as follows

```
    <?php
    include 'config.php';
    $item_name = ($_POST["item_name"] <> "") ? trim( addslashes($_POST["item_name"])) : "";
    if ($country_id <> "" ) { 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sub_menu WHERE item_name = ".$item_name ." ORDER BY sub_item_name";
    $count = mysql_num_rows( mysql_query($sql) );
    if ($count > 0 ) {
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    ?>
    <select name="sub_item">
       <option value="">Please Select</option>
     <?php while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
       <option><?php echo $rs["item_name"]; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <?php 
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Is the AJAX call executing? If so, what is the response from the server?

Comment: @Ninsly how to check its executing or not.... when i select any value in first check box the second one just disappears... so i guess its going to the subitem.php but i don't know how to check that the value i am passing in going to that subitem.php page or not

Comment: If you're using a common browser, it should have dev tools (which can usually be toggled by pressing F12). There should be a Net or Network tab where you can track the requests.

Comment: I checked the tab Network and changed the method to GET... here is the value getting attached at the end of url subitem.php?item_name=1&_=1409753659406 thats what i got from dev tool and i checked the response tab as well but there is no data in that tab....

Comment: If you change the method to `GET` then the `$_POST` array will be empty. What is the response when it's `POST`?

Comment: @Ninsly yeah i got what you mean now because i checked other ajax autocomplete php file's response and there are some data in response file but there is none in subitem.php so i guess i am not getting any data right.. but how do i check that at least the data is passing to subitem.php or not....

Comment: In most dev tools you should be able to expand the request in the Network tab. There is usually then a subsection where you can view the parameters.

Comment: Ok @Ninsly i figured out a small problem and thats i am getting id of the item_name instead of actual name selected at the drop down

Comment: You could change `sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;` to `sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;` to grab the text instead of the value

Comment: @Ninsly Ohhh yeah.... its done... i used a little bit different approach because i wasn't getting any value passed to subitem.php when i used .text instead of .value... anyway its done now and thank you very much for you help everyone...

Answer (score 0):

This should

```
<option><?php echo $rs["item_name"]; ?></option>
```

to

```
<option value="<?php echo $rs["item_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["item_name"]; ?></option>
```

I given $rs["item_id"]; whatever field you want in value fix it.

And also,

change this line also

Comment: I still don't get that giving value=id will help or not and how it will help... but i did that anyway and still not getting any output... thank you for your replay anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your selectbox option should have value attributes. Until your condition `if (item_name.length > 0 ) {` should be fail.

```
  <option><?php echo $ukg[1]; ?></option>
```

Should be

```
  <option value="<?php echo YOUR_VALUE ?>"><?php echo $ukg[1]; ?></option> 



  <option><?php echo $rs["item_name"]; ?></option>
```

Should be

```
 <option value="<?php echo YOUR_VALUE ?>"><?php echo $rs["item_name"]; ?></option>
```

Also currently you are sending the object instead on value.

```
<select name="iname" id="iname" class="form-control" onChange="showSubItem(this);">
```

Should be

```
<select name="iname" id="iname" class="form-control" onChange="showSubItem(this.value);">
```

So you can access the selected value directly from your variable `sel`

`var item_name = sel;`

Comment: I don't know how that will help but i did it anyway and still not working

Comment: i @RajivRisi tried using this.value and item_name=sel but still when i select any value in first drop down the second one just disappears and displaying nothing

Comment: Check the response from subitem.php. Your are getting wrong output from that file. So it's over written with old selectbox.

Comment: tried to open the subitem.php directly in browser but no output i got and i tried to pass value in url as well but i didn't got any output so i don't know whats wrong yet..

Comment: Change the $_POST["item_name"] to $_REQUEST["item_name"] or $_GET["item_name"]

Comment: I changed it to GET at both places in script function as well and in subitem.php file too.... when i saw the response in dev tool there is not data and the file file being request is attached with this data subitem.php?item_name=1&_=1409753659406 and this is i got from the dev top network tab as well...

Answer (score 0):

You not defined the $country_id in subitem.php file, Thats why code fails to execute inside if statement. You define something for $country_id or remove the condition if not necessary. Then it will work

Example:

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';
    $country_id = 'something';
    $item_name = ($_POST["item_name"] <> "") ? trim( addslashes($_POST["item_name"])) : "";
    if ($country_id <> "" ) { 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM sub_menu WHERE item_name = ".$item_name ." ORDER BY sub_item_name";
    $count = mysql_num_rows( mysql_query($sql) );
    if ($count > 0 ) {
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    ?>
    <select name="sub_item">
       <option value="">Please Select</option>
     <?php while ($rs = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
       <option><?php echo $rs["item_name"]; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <?php 
      }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: actually @user787669 its my mistake in pasting the code here... its $item_name and i changed that but its still not working